# Convert text to csv rows separated by specific pattern

Tags: python

We have data as below in a log file, we need to convert this and put in a csv file, 
rows should be separated by '***************************************************************', 
can we do this in python.

```
Job : Job000001
Execution Date: 2010/01/01 00:05:00.00 PST Sun
App Name: App0001
Script : /oracle/dwh/scripts/test1.sh
***************************************************************
Job : Job000002
Execution Date: 2010/01/01 00:05:00.00 PST Sun
App Name: App0001
Script : /oracle/dwh/scripts/test2.sh
***************************************************************
Job : Job000003
Execution Date: 2010/01/01 00:05:00.00 PST Sun
App Name: App0001
Script : /oracle/dwh/scripts/test3.sh
***************************************************************
Job : Job000004
Execution Date: 2010/01/01 00:05:00.00 PST Sun
App Name: App0001
Script : /oracle/dwh/scripts/test5.sh
***************************************************************
```

the expected output is csv file as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Read text file line by line until you encounter **** and spilt each line with ':' and save data in dictionary and then write dictionary to CSV file.

Comment: import csv

with open('C:\Work\data\sample_data_line_sep.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
    with open('C:\Work\data\sample_data_line_sep..csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(('Job Details'))
        writer.writerows(lines)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link under your post to add your code, then format it by clicking on the `{ }` button on the toolbar. As you can see, the code becomes unreadable from the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code for this:

```
import csv
import itertools as it
with  open("input.txt") as f:
    list_=[]
    for key, group in it.groupby(f, lambda line: line.startswith('******')):
        if not key:
            d = {}
            for item in list(group):
                key1,value1 = item.split(":",1)
                d[key1] = value1.strip("\n")
            list_.append(d)
    print(list_)

keys1 = list_[0].keys()
with open('output.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys1)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(list_)
```

Comment: File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Work/python/data_line_sep.py", line 15, in <module>
    with open('C:\Work\data\sample_data_line_sep.csv', 'w') as output_file:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Work\\data\\sample_data_line_sep.csv'

Comment: @Sumanth That is a different problem. PermissionError means your script does not have permissions to write to the file, or maybe the file is still open somewhere and you are trying to overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by reading the log file , remove the unnecessary strings and then write the required strings to the csv file in the following manner!

```
import csv

with open("data.log","r") as file:
    out=file.readlines()

for i in out:
    if i == '***************************************************************\n':
        pass
    else:
        with open("out.csv","a+") as csv_file:
            print(i)
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            writer.writerow([i])
```

You can play around the csv.writer to get the format you want! You can start with this! Try reading about the `python csv` module!